# TableView does not call GetHeightForRow

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a class which inherits from `UITableViewSource` and overrides GetHeightForRow:

```
public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

However, at some point in time the OS stopped calling this method, so all my cells have the same height now. The rest of the table and table source is working fine. This is very strange, and I have tried all sorts of things, but it just does not call the method. The other overridden methods of the table source are called normally.

Is there some sort of a setting which makes the `UITableView` stop calling `GetHeightForRow`?

Comment: You mean in the same execution ? (works then stops) or it stopped working after a code update ?

Comment: What happens if you change the `NSIndexPath` parameter up there to be of type `UIMutableIndexPath`?

Comment: @poupou it stopped working after a code update, which had nothing to do with the tables however. It's very very strange, how can a code update of mine suddenly prevent iOS/Monotouch from calling `GetHeightForRow`, if `GetCell` and `RowsInSection` are still called..

Comment: @Paul I cannot compile with `UIMutableIndexPath`. It seems that class does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you be setting both a `Delegate` (or `WeakDelegate`) of type `UITableViewDelegate` and the `Source` (of type `UITableViewSource`) property ?

They both expose `GetHeightForRow` and they will conflict if both are used on the same `UITableView`.

Comment: thank you so much, that was it! that error must have been there since several commits, and I didn't notice until now..

Comment: Thank you again Sebastien, I just realized that `UITableViewSource` combines `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, so I don't need no additional delegate :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in ViewWillAppear method. This works out.

```
        TableView.Source = new ItemsSource ();
```