# GetHeightForRow not being called for custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin iOS Designer to implement a table with a custom UITableViewCell. My table view source looks like this:

```cs
public class StreamTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    PrayerCard[] cards;

    public StreamTableSource(PrayerCard[] items)
    {
        this.cards = items;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        PrayerCardCell cell = (PrayerCardCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell("prayercardcell");
        cell.Update(cards[indexPath.Row]);
        return cell;
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        float computedHeight = 50.0f; // fixed for now
        Console.WriteLine("Height: {0}", computedHeight); // never shows
        return computedHeight; 
    }        

    ...
}
```

The `GetHeightForRow` method never gets called and so I end up with standard 44 point rows. My `UITableViewController` only has a `UITableViewSource` and not a `UITableViewDelegate` so [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654700/tableview-does-not-call-getheightforrow), does not solve my problem.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you using self sizing cells? If yes, the method will never be called. Check this out: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: Thanks for the super link, @Krumelur. I'm afraid that is not it. I'm testing on an iOS 7 device and have never heard of this great feature.

Comment: What does your view controller look like? You should set the `Source` property only.

Comment: Yup. I only set `TableView.Source = new StreamTableSource(cards.ToArray());` in `ViewWillAppear` - no delegate or anything else.

Comment: Guess: set it earlier (1st thing in `ViewDidLoad()`).

Comment: That was it! Krumelur, if you can add that as an answer then I can mark it off. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewSource` is a combination of `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` (this exists on Xamarin.iOS only).

The method `float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)` is part of the delegate.

If the delegate is not set when the view has already been loaded, it seems to point to a default (empty) implementation. The result is that the delegate methods of `UITableViewSource` won't be called.

`UITableViewSource` must be set early enough, a good place is the beginning of `ViewDidLoad()` of the view controller.